# Codeigniter 4: authfilter filter must have a matching alias defined

Tags: linux, codeigniter-4

I'm new to Codeigniter 4.
I'm developing something localy (Win10/XAMPP) and everything works fine. I uploaded code to linux hosting and suddenly I got error: authfilter filter must have a matching alias defined. 'authfilter' was an allias name in Config/Filters file. Than I noticed that allias is lowercased filter class name, so I changed allias to authfil and now I am getting error: Class 'App\Filters\AuthFilter' not found (SYSTEMPATH/Filters/Filters.php at line 167).

Can anyone explain to me what makes the difference; same code, Windows vs. Linux.

My App/Config/Filters contains following code:

```
namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\DebugToolbar;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\Honeypot;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\InvalidChars;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\SecureHeaders;
use App\Filters\FilterInterface;
use App\Filters\AuthFilter;

class Filters extends BaseConfig
{
    /**
     * Configures aliases for Filter classes to
     * make reading things nicer and simpler.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $aliases = [
        'csrf'          => CSRF::class,
        'toolbar'       => DebugToolbar::class,
        'honeypot'      => Honeypot::class,
        'invalidchars'  => InvalidChars::class,
        'secureheaders' => SecureHeaders::class,
        'authfil'    => \App\Filters\AuthFilter::class,
    ];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that are always
     * applied before and after every request.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $globals = [
        'before' => [
            // 'honeypot',
            // 'csrf',
            // 'invalidchars',
            'authfil' ///=> ['except' => 'auth/login']
        ],
        'after' => [
            'toolbar',
            // 'honeypot',
            // 'secureheaders',
        ],
    ];
```

My routes looks like:

```
$routes->group('auth', ['filter' => 'authfil'],['namespace' => 'IonAuth\Controllers'], function ($routes) {
    $routes->get('/', 'Auth::index');
    $routes->add('login', 'Auth::login');
    $routes->get('logout', 'Auth::logout');
...
}
```

Thanx in advance,
Siniša

P.S. I put: use App\Filters\AuthFilter to SYSTEMPATH/Filters/Filters.php but with no success. I also tried to add filter to the route, and all combinations that I can think of before I post the question.
The fact is, my project is quite large and today, after few months of working, I find out that I should use filters for login check instead of put login check inside initController function... InitController function is a strange approach to me, instead of using standard OOP concepts (constructors). However, there is a reason for everything, even if it's not obvious to me :).

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75044784/edit) and share your `app/Config/Filters.php` file contents.

Comment: In addition, could you share areas of code in your project where this particular filter was applied? You most likely **forgot** to also rename the old *'alias'* that was used in your `app/Config/Routes.php` file. I.e: `$routes->add('home', 'Controllers\Home', ['filter' => 'authfilter']);`

Comment: Renaming usages of `authfilter` to `authfil` in the **whole** project files may resolve your issue.

Comment: Could you share your `App\Filters\AuthFilter` class file contents as well?

Comment: I'm going step by step... Everything is working on my local machine even without filter in the routes... So I carefully add filter to auth group in routes just to see the difference.  Locally that won't work if I add filter to the route group admin;

Comment: In your particular case, there is **no** need to specify a route *'auth filter'* (`['filter' => 'authfil']`) in your route definitions since that is *implicitly* applied on all web routes already by adding the *'auth filter'* to the `Config\Filters::$globals` array.

Comment: That seems reasonable. Everything was working localy even before i added filter to the route :).

Comment: and... I gave up on the filter; initController I bow to you, you're working no matter of backgrouind OS :)